# Copy git repo via ftp

Tags: git, ftp

I have the git repo created on my local machine. And I have the FTP-server. I have to copy my repo to that server. But my local machine is under the NAT so I have not IP and can't simply run 'git clone' on that server. I've tried to just copy my repo folder via FTP but than I've get a multiple errors when run any git command in the folder created that way.

So is there a way to clone repo without using 'clone' comand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can SSH from your local machine to the FTP server (I assume you can, as you want to use git there). The simplest should be to set up an ssh tunnel (also called port forwarding) when connecting. You should be then able to reach your local box from the FTP server even if it's under NAT.

Try this on local box:

```
ssh ftpserver -R 4567:localhost:22
```

While the above connection is up, you should be able to reach your local box (under NAT) using:

```
ssh -p 4567 localhost
```

I am not sure how your are accessing the git repo for cloning, but you should be able to figure out the ports.

Comment: putty has the same functionality

Comment: Wow! Nice trick! Only you have not go to your local machine after you establish that tunnel. Only do 'git clone ssh://username@localhost:4567/path/to/repo'

Comment: Or if you simply copy repo to server via **scp** - that's works too. [ssh rules?]

Comment: I am glad that helped you, I wasn't sure if you were cloning git over ssh, or git protocol. So I didn't know what the second command should be in your case. I just wanted to demonstrate the tunnel with the second command.